# Url Amigables con .htaccess cambiar un parámetro por texto

Tags: php, mysqli, .htaccess

Tengo una web desarrollada en [php](/questions/tagged/php) y [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) ahora deseo utilizar URL Amigables a mis enlaces.

Tengo por ejemplo el enlace tradicional:

```
midominio.com/portal/public/oficinas.php?seccion=24
```

24 es a la sección: oficina

En esta pagina me muestra la lista de oficinas:

- Logística
- Atención al publico

Intento que me muestre en URL amigable:

```
midominio.com/portal/public/oficinas
```

Ahora también tengo esta URL:

```
midominio.com/portal/public/oficinasDetalle.php?seccion=24&categoria=56
```

Donde mi sección es: oficinas y categoría es

Intento que sea así mi URL:

```
midominio.com/portal/public/oficinas/logistica
```

Son 2 enlaces uno que me muestra la lista de oficinas y la otra que me muestra el detalle de la oficina, como seria en `.htaccess` para hacer enlaces amigables así como explico lineas arriba.

Por ejemplo cuando el usuario escribe un enlace que no existe me muestre un error 403.

**En realidad ya hice esto:**

```
Option +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Ahora en mi index.php que se encuentra en la raiz de portal:

```
if ($parte_url=="oficinas") {
  include_once(public/oficinas) 
}else {
  echo "error 404";
}
```

Mi link queda así:

```
misitio.com/portal/oficinas
```

Hasta ahii todo perfecto me muestra la lista de oficinas, asi como deseo, ahora tengo este link donde me muestra el detalle de una oficina

midominio.com/portal/public/oficinasDetalle.php?seccion=24&categoria=56

Y desearia que quede asi:

```
misitio.com/portal/oficinas/logistica
```

Por favor ayuda.. solo me falta eso para poder publicarla en la web.

o si tienen otra idea de como hacerlo pues si me pueden ayudar a implementar

Comment: Y qué has intentado?

Comment: Cuando hablas de dos enlaces, hablas de uno con categoría y otro sin ella?

Answer (score 3):

Añade esto a tu .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?page=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

Aquí estas indicando que mostrarás la url únicamente con el contenido de la expresión regular

```
[^&\ ]+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
href="<?=base_url?>indice/listar">
```

Comment: ¿Qué estás intentando decir con ese código?

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo genérico para simplificar las reglas htaccess y darle trabajo al index.php

primero capturamos todo lo que viene en la url despues del servidor y se lo pasamos a index.php (las dos primeras condiciones es que no haga esto si ya existe una carpeta o archivo con ese nombre)

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Luego en el index.php transformamos esa ruta que viene en forma de cadena a un array y "restamos" las carpetas de donde está alojado el mismo php (de las cosas que vienen del apache)

```
<?php

$request = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$script = explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$categorias=array_values(array_diff($request,$script));


// hacemos un mini debug para ver como funciona internamente
echo '<pre>';
print_r($categorias);
echo "<hr />";

echo "*** lo que viene del server:<br />";
var_dump($_SERVER);
echo "*** la ruta filtrada por htaccess:<br />";
var_dump($request);
echo "*** la ruta de este script en el servidor:<br />";
var_dump($script);

echo '</pre>';

?>
```

En el array `$categorias` te quedan las partes de la url que luego deberás transformar en números para cargar el contenido

para tu ejemplo (lo escribo literal pero seguramente lo vas a hacer dinámico consultando una tabla de secciones y categorías)

```
$seccion=0;
$categoria=0;

if ('oficinas'==$categorias[0]) $seccion=24;
if ('logistica'==$categorias[1]) $categoria=56;

echo "index.php?seccion=$seccion&categoria=$categoria<br />"
```