# ¿hay alguna manera de recibir datos de la url sin usar $_GET en PHP?

Tags: php, api, variables, get

Vi una pagina en la que muestra imágenes al azar que funciona recolectando datos según la url, los usuarios ponen en la url las dimensiones de la imagen y se muestra, pero no es como la variable que conozco `$_GET` de PHP **index.php?x=0&y=1**, en cambio la url era **index.php/0/1**.
¿Cuál es el método aplicado para obtener estos datos?

Soy principiante en esto espero que me ayuden

Url de la página: https://picsum.photos/50/50

Comment: por lo general se hace reescribiendo con .htaccess (apache), un ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/152409/81450 para nginx va en el conf del dominio

Comment: En ese caso el metodo sigue siendo GET, simplemente que la url fue reescrita, se hace esto con el fin de tener una url mas amigable para el usuario final, esto es a través de mod_rewrite (o htaccess como lo indica @aloMalbarez en su comentario).

Es por ello que se recomienda el uso de frameworks como CakePhp, Laravel, Zend Framework entre otros que te ayudan a gestionar estos detalles.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es coger la url, extraer lo que hay detrás del dominio (path) con parse_url() y después meter los trozos del path en un array de fragmentos.

```
$url= 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$fragmentos = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH) = explode($fragmentos);
$ancho_imagen = $fragmentos[0];
$alto_imagen = $fragmentos[1];
```