# Archivo .htaccess en PHP y hoja de rutas

Tags: php

Tengo una API en PHP que la consumo desde angular:

```
export class ApiarticuloService {


  url: string = 'http://localhost:80/index.php/articulo/index';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
    ) { 
    
  }
  getArticulos(): Observable<apiResponse>{
    return this.http.get<apiResponse>(this.url);
  }

  add(articulo:articulo): Observable<Response>{
    return this.http.post<Response>(this.url,articulo,httpOption);
  }
  edit(articulo:articulo):Observable<Response>{

    return this.http.put<Response>(`${this.url}/${articulo.idproducto}`,articulo,httpOption);
  }
  delete(id:number):Observable<Response>{
    return this.http.delete<Response>(`${this.url}/${id}`);
  }
}
```

Anteriormente trabaja con MVC con las vistas en el mismo php, es decir contenido html en la carpeta "views".
Ahora al usar angular me gustaria que al invocar:

**http://localhost:80/index.php/articulo/index**

Me detecte el controlador y la accion, para lo mismo modifique mi archivo .htaccess de la siguiente manera:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}v1/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Pero no funciona, el navegador me devuelve http failure. Pero ademas queria saber como codificar la hoja de rutas para tomar el controlador y la accion:

De momento tengo esto:

```
   $controller=$_GET["controller"];
   $action=$_GET["action"];
   require_once('controllers/' . $controller . '_controller.php');


     switch($controller){
     case 'articulo':
       $controllerArticulo = new VentaController();
       switch ($action){
           case 'index':
               $controllerArticulo->index();
               break;
           
}
```

Comment: Esta bien la ruta? %{ENV:BASE}v1 con v1?

Comment: Quiza ahi estaba el problema, voy a publicar la solucion

Comment: `!-d` en htacces verifica q (no) sea una carpeta , `QSA` es query string append, si no pasas parametros extra en la url no sería necesario, incluso podes usar `QSD` = query string discad.  para que no distinga mayúsculas usas `NC` (No case) 
 `L` es última (last) asi que si hay otras reglas deberían ir antes, en general [NC,L] suele bastar para urls del tipo '/unaCosa/otracosa'  https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/152409/81450

Answer (score 0):

Al final deje mi archivo .htaccess de la siguiente manera:

```
Options All -Indexes
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
```

Entonces tengo:

```
<?php
include_once 'controllers/loginController.php';
//include_once 'routes.php';
$usuario=$_POST["usuario"];
$contraseña=$_POST['contraseña'];

$login=new LoginController();
$array=$login->crearToken($usuario,$contraseña);

if ($array){
   
$routesArray = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$routesArray= array_filter($routesArray);

if (count($routesArray)==0){
    $json = array(

        'status'=>404,
        'result'=>'not found'

    );
    echo json_encode($json, http_response_code($json['status']));
}else{
    require_once('controllers/' . $routesArray[3] . 'Controller.php');


      switch($routesArray[3]){
      case 'articulo':
        $controllerArticulo = new articuloController();
        switch ($routesArray[4]){
            case 'index':
                $controllerArticulo->index();
                break;
           
        
    }
}
}
}
?>
```

donde **$routesArray[3]** es el nombre de controlador y **$routesArray[4]** el nombre de la accion.