# Regla para manejar directorio de la URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

estoy configurando mi `.htaccess` para poner en producción mi web y el caso es que no lo termino de entender o no me llevo muy bien con este archivo y me da problemas y confuncion a la vez

tengo la siguiente estructura de directorios

```
controller
models
view 
   └clientes
           └agregar.php
           └editar.php
   └home
   └ etc..
   └index.php
index.php
.htaccess
```

El .htaccess lo tengo configurado ahora mismo así:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /miproyecto/
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

en el index yo tomo la variable ruta

```
 $ruta = $_GET['ruta'];

if ($ruta == "index") {
                    include 'View//home/modules.php';
                } else if ($ruta == "home") {
                    include 'View//home/home.php';
                } else {
                    $URL = $ruta . '/' . $ruta . ".php";
                    // echo $URL;
                    include 'View/' . $URL;
                }
```

y segun la ruta incluyo el archivo que se necesita
pero ahora por ejemplo tengo la url **clientes\agregarclientes.php**
en la url aparezca **clientes\agregar clientes** o **clientes \ editar clientes**

pero como solo incluyo las los archivos que tengan el mismo nombre que la carpeta para mi es como un error

de su ayuda

Comment: si estas intentando hacer un mvc desde 0???

Comment: asi es estimado amigo, pero es primera vez que lo hago desde 0 con todo y configuraciones

Comment: fijate si te sirve este ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/152409/81450 basicamente es: si lo que piden no es un file (`!-f`) ni es un dir (`!-d`) pasale la url al index.php y ahí desglosas la url a como te vaya evolucionando la app

Comment: he probado las indicaciones del link que me has proporcionado pero no me funcionan, cuando cambio de directorio